# Problem "No operational system found" when booting from usb HDD (14.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, 14.04, usb, live-usb

I have a pretty modern ultrabook (Sony Vaio Pro 13) that doesn't have an internal HDD or OS. I want to use an external HDD, connected via USB, to use as "an internal drive" with Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it. I've read threads and answered question on how to do it. In short terms I have:

- Booted my computer from a LiveUSB pendrive (works fine)
- Installed Ubuntu on an antother USB-HDD (with this guide: http://www.fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/installubuntutousbdrive.html , works fine)
- Now when I have successfully installed it on the USB-HDD and tries to boot from it, it says:

  ```
  No operational system found
  ```

Any suggestions why? Boot mode is in Legacy, which works when booting from the LiveUSB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some usb thumdrives and external HDDs show up as internal drives in Bios.
If this is the case change the harddrive boot order in your Bios.

Comment: Somehow when I swapped boot priority and then swapped again it started working. I have now 1st priority external. It seems to work now. Thank you for your help!